# UITableView section with clearColor background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a ViewController with a radial gradient background. Inside that I have a UITableView with cells and sections. Now I want to show the gradient behind the table view as you scroll. The issue is that when the section locks at the top you can see the cells behind the section. I would set the section background color but if I do that it does not match the radial gradient background. Is there anyway to have the cells clip under the sections while keeping the clearColor background?

Comment: can you post a screen shot? Having a hard time visualizing this.

Comment: You can set tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if I understand it, you want a completely clear tableview and tableview cell so you can see the background of your view controller.

You can achieve this by setting the tableview as having no background

```
tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

and also the cell

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

if you also want the section to be transparent, you can use this method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

to make a custom view (for example create an image view with a transparent .png for the background)

I hope I understand your question correctly.

---

**edit after clarification**

to give the appearance that the cells stop before going underneath the section header:

make a class that is a subclass of uitableview with this ivar:

```
@interface CustomTableView : UITableView
{
        CAGradientLayer* maskLayer;
}
```

obviously this will create a gradient but if you wanted you could either tweak it or use `CALayer` and instead of programmatically creating the mask, create a .png with the correct width/height of your section header.

ANYWAY: if you use the `CAGradientLayer`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) 
    {
        [self setupGradients]; //call your method
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupGradients
{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:0 context:nil];

    */ ***** if you choose to use CALayer instead of CAGradient ****** */
    //maskLayer = [[CALayer layer] retain]; 
    //maskLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"maskLayer.png"].CGImage; 
    //maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; 
    */ ***** if you choose to use CALayer instead of CAGradient ****** */

    maskLayer = [[CAGradientLayer layer] retain];

    CGColorRef outerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef innerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)outerColor, 
                        (id)innerColor, (id)innerColor, (id)outerColor, nil];
    maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]; //this creates a gradient     effect. Tweak these numbers for a hard line. 

    maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{        
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    maskLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

then in your view controller:

```
   CustomTableView *_tableView; //ivar

   _tableView = [[CustomTableView alloc] initWithFrame:YOUR_FRAME];
```

The basic idea is a mask, you create a mask shape on the top of your tableview that is the same size as your section header. it will appear that the cells "disappear" behind it. It's a bit tricky, but it will work.

Comment: You are understanding what I'm trying to achieve but not the problem I am having. The issue is that my sections are transparent so you can see the cells as they pass behind the section. This creates a mix of the cell and section which looks terrible. I appreciate the answer though, thanks

Comment: ah I understand now. Interesting question. I have an idea of how you can do it, but it's a bit hacky. I will edit my answer above.

Answer (score 10):

Simple way to get a transparent section header without creating your own header views.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

This piece of code works perfectly fine in iOS 7.

**EDIT**
I know this is a little late, but along with this you have to add 2 lines making sure the background color (and background color of the background view?) of the uitableview is also clear.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```